# Verify number of times window.close was called - cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, chai

I have created stub for `window.close` for cypress I want to know number of times it has been called .

```
 cy.window().then(win => {
   cy.stub(win, 'close').as('parentWindowCalled');
 });
```

I want to check whether `window.close` is never called .  How can I do that ?

Comment: The question is unanswerable - never called by when? How long do you want to wait?

Answer (score 1):

You would need the stub object

```js
let stub
cy.window().then(win => {
  stub = cy.stub(win, 'close').as('parentWindowCalled');
})

// actions
cy.wait('@parentWindowCalled')
cy.wait('@parentWindowCalled')
cy.wait('@parentWindowCalled')

cy.then(() => expect(stub).to.have.been.called.exactly(3))
```

`to.have.been.called` is just extracting the call count from the spy, so you can chain other criteria like `.have.been.called.at.least(3)`.

Comment: What if it is never called , that is 0 times can I use this ?

Comment: Yes, but obviously you would change what your test expectation is.

Comment: No it is failing like @parentWindowCalled  was never called